# Copy to another div as you type in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to reproduce the same thing as stackoverflow does when you start typing in the editor it copies.

I have a input text and the text they enter I want it to be copied to another div as they type.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code and perhaps we can help with your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input').keypress(function() {
       $('#output').html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Example/demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/SYwpy/

Comment: A simple/basic starting point.  This obviously can be tweaked/improved.

Comment: Thanks.  Almost perfect.  Its always missing the last letter.  Thanks for jsfilldle.net (nice tool)

Comment: yeah I figured it'd be a simple tweak to take care of that.  sorry didn't have time to perfect it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reproduce exactly what is here, did you look at the source?

I think this is what they use:

http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/source/browse/wmd.js

Search in the file for the function pushPreviewHtml. You will see this line which may be of interest:

```
wmd.panels.output.innerHTML = "<pre><code>" + newText + "</code></pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input').keyup(function() {
       $('#output').html($(this).val());
    });
});
```